# Updating an Update Panel requires two clicks of a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I apologize if this has been asked but i cant seem to find the exact right answer to my question.

I have a button that updates a gridview that is inside of an update panel.  also inside the update panel are 3 labels.  the labels are used for errors.  if a button is clicked and data is added to the database that should add to the gridview, i do not see it.  however, if the button is clicked again, one of the error labels displays saying that the data already exists, and then i see the new data in the gridview.  I actually have a couple of update panels that the same button click updates, inside those i have drop down menus, same thing happens, it takes two clicks.  update panel looks like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSloPitchLeague" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvLeague" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" CellPadding="5" DataKeyNames="leagueID">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="leagueDay" HeaderText="Day" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="leagueType" HeaderText="Type" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDayError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblTypeError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDBError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddLeague" EventName="Click" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Why did you chose the AsyncPostBackTrigger instead of putting the button inside the UpdatePanel?

Comment: Can you provide the code how you bind this grid, both at the very first time and after data has been added into database?

Answer (score 0):

The original answer to this question was deleted due to it being a link-only answer to JS Bin.  For reference only: jsbin[dot]com/nanuvihune/1/edit

Here is the version I was editing when it got deleted:

```js
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
  dataTextField: "Name",
  dataSource: [{
      id: 1,
      Name: "Apples"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      Name: "Oranges"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      Name: "Carrots"
    }
  ],
  select: function(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    alert(dataItem.id);
  }
});
var autocomplete = $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2014.1.416/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="autocomplete" />
```